# component in react js not rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in React which I am importing in index.js, but it is giving this error:  Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const Intro = (props) => {
  <p className="App-intro">
    To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload
  </p>
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">

          <h1 className="App-title">TV Series list</h1>
        </header>
        <Intro />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
const Intro = (props) => {
  <p className="App-intro">
    To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload
  </p>
}
```

Doesn't have a return statement.

If you wrap it within brackets `{}` then you need to have a return statement within the component. You don’t have to do this if it’s wrapped in parentheses though, because the syntax implies a return

Also, you’re not exporting `Intro`

Comment: yep, this to :)

Comment: const Intro = (props) => (
  <p className="App-intro">
    To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload
  </p>
);  works though

Comment: You don't have to when used in same file, just if you want to reach it externally

Comment: Yes it does, the return is implied in an arrow-function if you use that syntax. You can't do any logic with that method though, only what's inside the return.

Comment: That makes sense, if he executes it inside {} it’s a completely different syntax though, I think that would cause an error yeah? The server would be expecting a return statement inside of that, whereas if it’s just () the return is already implied

Answer (score 1):

```
const Intro = (props) => (
  <p className="App-intro">
    To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload
  </p>
)
```

OR

```
const Intro = (props) => {
  return (<p className="App-intro">
    To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload
  </p>);
}
```

Here in your code you have used `{}` in arrow function body but it does not return anything, hence no element/component is rendering. You can return the value from arrow function using any of the above method. Here `()` assumes that the only statement in body is *return* statement while `{}` requires explicit *return* statement.

Probably your error statement is because `Intro` is one stateless component.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is called `index.js` as you said, that's probably the error.

You have jsx in your code therefore your file must be named: 
`index.jsx`

:)